# Multiple values in pandas df column and sum another column values

Tags: python, pandas

Data:

```
           Person          Time
1     person1               20
2     person1;person2       60
3     person2;person3       100
```

I have a code that counts individual values:

```
df['Person'].str.split(";", expand=True).stack().value_counts()
```

However, I want to take it a step further and sum up all the Time values for every Person in df. Output should be:

```
person1 - 80
person2 - 160
person3 - 100
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) with reassign column `Person` by splitted values and aggregate `sum`:

```
out = (df.assign(Person=df['Person'].str.split(";"))
         .explode('Person')
         .groupby('Person', as_index=False)
         .sum())
print (out)
    Person  Time
0  person1    80
1  person2   160
2  person3   100
```